# When I open python3.6 from windows10 build 9845, python prompts api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

> OS:Windows10 build 9845 x64
>
> python ver:python3.6.1

I tried to install python 3.6.1 on my computer, python can be installed normally, but when I start python, it prompts api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing.

I Attempted to install the Visual C++ Redistributable, but it does not work. In addition, I was unable to install the KB2999226 patch on my computer, suggesting that this patch does not apply to your computer.

Finally, I try to download this dll from the Internet to register, but when I open python he will prompt other dlls to be lost.

I do not want to install windows7 or windows10.

How can I do it? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Installed vc-redist.x64 (Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015) from [microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
and Python 3.6.5 32-bit (on Windows 7 64-bit) from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and the above error (api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing) is gone.